# Appending 1D Ndarray to 2D Ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm attempting to append a 1D array which have generated by appending elements one at a time to a 2D array as a new row in the array.

```
    a = np.ones((2, 5), int)
    b = np.empty((0, 5), int)

    b = np.append(b, [1])
    b = np.append(b, [2])
    b = np.append(b, [3])
    b = np.append(b, [4])
    b = np.append(b, [5])

    a = np.append(a, b, axis=0)

    print(b)
```

I'm pretty lost as to why this code doesn't work? They are both arrays of 5 elements, but get the following error? "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"

Comment: stay away from `np.append`, especially if you can't read its documentation.

Comment: Can you write/draw out the two arrays you're trying to merge, and then write/draw out what you want the merged array to look like? That will help us direct you to the most appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: I find it hard to understand your question. `a` and `b` already have different `dim`

Comment: `a` is (2,5), `b` is (5,)

Comment: np.hstack or np.vstack might be more appropriate based on what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You probably mean `a = np.append(a, [b], axis=0)`.

Comment: @CristiFati You are correct, that is what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a and b have different `dim` a is (2,5) and b is (5,) reshape b to be (1,5).

Then you can append `b` row-wise as following:

```
result=np.append(a,b.reshape(1,-1),axis=0)
```

Comment: This method works as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` is trying to concatenate a 1D array (`b`) with a 2D array (`a`) along a specific axis, but `b` doesn't have the same number of dimensions as `a`.

use `vstack` instead of `append`:

```py
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a = np.vstack((a, b))
```

```py
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a = np.concatenate((a, b[np.newaxis, :]), axis=0)
```

In the above examples, `b` is first reshaped to a 2D array with shape (1,5) and then concatenated to `a`.